# php using strpos to exclude multiple word replace multiple comparisons in an if statement

Tags: php

How can I use `strpos` to exclude multiple words? I am using this code but it looks ugly.

```
if (strpos($ul_n, 'word1') === false) {
if (strpos($ul_n, 'word2') === false) {
if (strpos($ul_n, 'word3') === false) {
if (strpos($ul_n, 'word4') === false) {
/----do something
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to put the words you're looking for in an array and loop over them. After the loop, if none of them were found, you can do your "something".

```
$found_word = false;
foreach (['word1','word2','word3','word4',] as $word) {
    if (strpos($ul_n, $word) !== false) {
        $found_word = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$found_word) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You can also use `break` in the loop so you don't keep looking once a word is found.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of nested `if`s you can combine them with `&&`:

```
if (strpos($ul_n, 'word1') === false && strpos($ul_n, 'word2') === false && ...) {
    // do something
}
```

But a simpler way is with a regular expression:

```
if (!preg_match('/word1|word2|word3|word4/') {
    // do something
}
```

`|` in a regular expression specifies alternatives, so this matches whenever any of the words matches.